# Accessing python dataframe columns in vim editor upon pressure of a key

Tags: gvim, python, plugin-jedi-vim

I have the following situation

```
import pandas as pd
T = read_csv("MyFile")
```

I would like to have a list of the dataframe `T` columns when I type `T["` and then I hit a key like `<tab>` or `<c-space>` or by using some `vim omnicompletion` functions (`<c-x><c-o>`?`<c-x><c-p>`?`<c-x><c-n>`?) or by exploiting some plug-in like for example `vim-jedi` (that I have installed).

Note that if on an `ipython` console I type `T["` followed by a `<tab>`, then I got a list of options, including the columns of the dataframe.

Comment: This may not be viable in the general case. You would need to execute the entire program up to that point in order to know what the columns are, which presents a risk (to me).